# Ищу способ получить шрифт системное имя которого состоит из набора латинских и кириллических букв

Tags: windows, шрифты, кириллица, autocad

У меня есть файлы автокада сохраненные в Autocad 2007. На время выпуска того автокада (2006 г.), актуальной была Windows XP. И только-только появилась Vista. В консоли автокада я вижу

```
Подстановка [simplex.shx] вместо [Times New Roman Кириллический].
Подстановка [simplex.shx] вместо [Tahoma Кириллический].
```

Мне менять подстановку в 40 очень многослойных файлах очень унизительно! Легче скопировать файл из папки C:\Windows\Fonts, открыть в программе типа FontForge и переименовать, а затем скопировать обратно а папку с шрифтами или нажать "Установить"(у меня Win 7), но вот только не принимает эта прожка кириллицу в поле названия шрифта. Я с консолью дружу очень хорошо. Мне подойдут рецепты которые можно выполнить в Windows/Linux, bash/cmd, GUI/no-GUI.

Да, искал в интернете уже переименнованые шрифты. Скиньте ссылку, если плохо искал. Но меня более интересует не "рыба", а "море и удочка".

Comment: Я может тоже плохо гуглю, но по запросу `simplex.shx` яндекс выдал http://acad-prog.ru/skachat-shrifty-avtokad/ а в ней есть ещё ссылка на http://acad-prog.ru/shrifty-avtokad/ . Это оно?

Comment: @donRumata, моя проблема в том, что при запросе "Times New Roman Кириллический" google выдает шрифты с системным названием "Times New Roman", и моему автокаду на клич "Таньяна", Таня молчит.  Все что нужно сделать это изменить имя. У меня получилось сделать со шрифтом Tahona, но Times New Roman не поддается [такому приему](http://www.fontgeek.net/blog/?p=435).

Answer (score 2):

Никогда не переименовывай существующие шрифты для получения файла с именем отсутствующего у тебя шрифта. Этим ты создашь огромные проблемы для пользователей!

Если AutoCAD не находит штифт, используемый в твоём чертеже, то он вместо него подставляет тот, который прописан в настройках AutoCAD:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обозначенный на скрине элемент отображает значение переменной `FONTALT`. Также ты можешь изменить значение этой переменной через консоль AutoCAD.

После изменения значения этой переменной нужно перезапускать AutoCAD, чтобы он подхватил это изменение.

AutoCAD ищет ресурсы в различных каталогах последовательно. В процессе поиска он так же выполняет их поиск по каталогам, указанным в настройках Support File Search Path:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причём поиск выполняется именно в том порядке, в каком перечислены эти каталоги. Т.е. самый верхний смотрится первым, а самый нижний - последним. Соответственно, если у тебя нужный файл шрифта находится в нескольких из этих каталогах, то использоваться будет тот, который будет найден первым.

Если ты видишь, что AutoCAD использует шрифт с правильным именем, но текст отображается некорректно, то либо это неверный файл шрифта (например кто-то взял и просто переименовал другой, произвольный шрифт - за это нужно отрывать ручки, ибо в разных файлах шрифта для одного и того же символа могут быть назначены совершенно разные числовые коды), либо AutoCAD использует одноимённый файл шрифта, но не из того каталога, который ты ожидал. Чтобы понять, что файл переименован - можешь сравнить их размеры и контрольные суммы.

Чтобы понять, какой именно файл используется (т.е. чтобы получить полное имя файла), в консоли AutoCAD запусти lisp-функцию:

`(findfile "имя_и_расширение_твоего_файла")`

Всё то, о чём я написал выше, легко находится в справке самого AutoCAD.

**UPD**

Если ты хочешь настроить подмену шрифтов индивидуально под каждый конкретный шрифт, т.е. шрифт A всегда подменять шрифтом B, и шрифт С всегда подменять шрифтом D, то ты можешь прописать эти замены в текстовом файле, указанном в опции Font Mapping File (т.е. не переименовывая никаких файлов):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полагаю, что синтаксис указанного файла не вызовет у тебя затруднений. Если что - в справке можно найти более подробную информацию.

Comment: У меня в одном файле много шрифтов. И замену нужно прописать индивидуально. Типа так:
- Tahoma Кириллический --> Tahoma,  
- Times New Roman Кириллический --> Times New Roman,  
- ... и так около 5-7 замен в 32 файлах на одних и тех же шрифтах.

Спасибо но переименование шрифтов сработало как можно лучше.

Comment: Переименование может привести к тому, что теперь текст твоих чертежей некорректно будет отображаться на компьютерах тех пользователей, у которых присутствует настоящий шрифт (т.е. не переименованный).

Comment: Я добавил секцию UPD в ответе.

Comment: Да fontmapping это наверное то, что я искал. В следующий раз воспользуюсь).
Переименование не приводит ни к чему для других пользователей, так как я не меняю DWG-файл, а делаю дубликат системного шрифта с целью сохранить оригинальный шрифт и иметь точно такой же под нужным мне именем. В результате переименования и установки шрифтов с переписаным именем в моей папке C:\Windows\Fonts будет 2 шрифта Tahoma и Tahoma Кириллический.

Comment: пробовал, то  что вы предлагали. Было легко.

Comment: Я не понял предыдущей фразы.